# PrimeNG calendar error - Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular4-forms, primeng-calendar

I am trying to implement PrimeNG calendar for date time pricker in my angular 4 application. I did the following installation.

```
>npm install primeng --save
```

module.ts

```
import { Calendar } from 'primeng/primeng'
```

component.ts

```
import { Calendar } from 'primeng/primeng'
```

Component.html

When I run the site, I am getting the following error.

> Template pasrse errors:
>       'p-calendar' is not a known element:
>       1. If 'p-calendar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>       2. If 'p-calendar' is a web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message ....

Can you help me out to bring the date time pricker in angular 4 ? Thanks.

Comment: You just need to import CalendarModule from 'primeng/primeng';

Comment: Thanks man, Its working fine now :) +1 up..

Answer (score 3):

In module.ts you additionally have to import your Calendar if it is a Module

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CalendarModule
],
```

or to declare it if it is a Component

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Calendar
],
```

I guess you didn't do that in either case referring to your post.

Comment: Please, be so kind and mark this answer as solution if it is.

Comment: Thanks for your kind response @DiabolicWords.. Bt it didnt not wrk.. Imported "CalendarModule" & it starts working..

Comment: Glad to hear that! :)  I wasn't aware of the fact that there is an additional CalendarModule. But still I'd appreciate you to mark my answer as solution as I gave you the right hint. Thx in advance.

Comment: @watraplion answer is now correct. Would you mind marking it as the answer, so others can benefit from it? This answer did help me. Thanks.